# How to use Java options in Spring Boot pom file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-opts, javaoptions

I am getting an error when I try to run the integration test (`@SpringBootTest`) in my application. I got a solution to use below the Java option

**--add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED**

I have checked it by editing the run configuration and it is working completely. (Run test case with above argument)

But I want to add through the pom file so when I run **mvn clean install** then it should work. I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>
                    --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I have also checked **-Djava.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED** It is also not working.
What is the right way to use this JVM argument so it can set runtime?

Comment: What exactly was the error you got: `I am getting an error when I try to run the integration test`??? It would also help to get the exact spring boot version, JDK version etc. you are using?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using ignite-core maven dependency in pom and it works well til Java 8. But now I want to use Java 17 and ignite-core does not work with the above Java 8  version directly.  We need to add JVM arguments in Java option 

https://www.appsloveworld.com/java/100/360/how-to-fix-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-ignite-ignitejdbcthindriver-er

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started#running-ignite-with-java-11-and-later-versions

Comment: @khmarbaise
 I am getting below error while run springboot test with java 17
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver

Answer (score 1):

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` doesn't run your tests. It's Maven's Surefire plugin that does that. You need to configure its [`argLine` property](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank You, Andy Wilkinson !! It worked for me